Is there any way to get an exponential speedup with quantum algorithm without quantum computer?
I am a student in Oxford University and I am studying a quantum computing?
And my goal is to make a computer what can improve speed exponentially vs classical computer.
Is there any way to get an exponential speedup with quantum algorithm without quantum computer?

What are you asking? Edit your question for clarity.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Let's assume that there are algorithms that run on a quantum computer exponentially faster than any classical computer. (This is not proven.) By definition, no classical computing device can achieve that speed up. You need to use some hardware that has some capabilities beyond classical. That is exactly the concept of a quantum computer. So, it's pretty much by definition that you need a quantum computer to achieve the exponential speedup. It may not be necessary to have a universal quantum computer - it may be possible to have a fixed function device that demonstrates the speedup, but it will have to work at the quantum level.

Great! I totally agree with you!
